# Optional navigation property in EF4 Code First

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to map the following entity and the problem is that EF makes CloseUserID as required even when they are not annotated with Required attribute.

```
 public class UserRegistration {
    [Key]
    public string RegistrationID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public Nullable<DateTime> ClosedAt { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public int CloseUserID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CloseUserID")]
    public virtual User CloseUser { get; set; }
  }
```

How can I make EF understand that CloseUserID is optional and not required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put

```
public int? CloseUserID { get; set; }
```

This is it. You don't need to put that FK annotation above the navigation property.

Comment: Thank you, I'm used to using string as foreign key which makes them optional by default.